# My usb flash memory is not detected in linux

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

My removable usb flash memory is not detected in linux. I test 2 systems:  suse and ubunto. Off course it is listed by lsusb command but in fsdisk or df ty it is not listed. It light on, but not detected. On the other hand It is detected in another windows 7 pc. There i format it from exfat to ntfs, fat32 but no result in suse and ubunto. I remember that some time i work to make these usb bootable and have some try to send iso file to it, May be it is the cause. I appreciate any advises.

Comment: What is your system config/OS setup?

Comment: please add exact output of lsusb and `/proc/partitions` to the question.